# CKAN : Linking an additional DB with existing datastore

Tags: postgresql, ckan

I am trying to add an additional database to CKAN (to store audit meta data and link to the main database), so that this will also be visible in the CKAN environment. Is this possible and if so are there any examples available? If not, what are my alternative options?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want a CKAN to display dataset metadata records that are stored in two databases.

There is the [Postgres foreign data wrapper](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/postgres-fdw.html), but you become unstuck when writing new dataset records.

Your alternative is to copy all the records into one database.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: https://github.com/cphsolutionslab/ckanext-dataproxy

It let's you use foreign databases similarly to the datastore database. Not exactly what you want, but if every dataset had a "foreign metadata" resource and you built in a preview of it on the dataset page template, it might be a workaround.

Otherwise you'll need to build an extension that does what you want.